# symfony doctrine update from form

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm stuck since this morning with the update of an entity.
Don't know what I'm missing, pretty sure this is a newbie mistake.

I'm just trying to update something via a form.

The controller:

```
public function editAction($pid, $plid, Request $request)
{
    $plan = new Plan();
    $form = $this->createForm(new PlanType(), $plan);

    $plan = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('QArthFrameworkBundle:Plan')->findOneByPlid($plid);
    $project = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('QArthFrameworkBundle:Project')->findOneByPid($pid);

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('qarth_framework_plan_edit', array('pid' => $pid, 'plid' => $plid)));
    }

    return $this->render('QArthFrameworkBundle:Pages:plan_edit.html.twig', array(
        'plan' => $plan,
        'project' => $project,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

The form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name');
    $builder->add('description', 'textarea');
}
```

The Entity : http://pastebin.com/bTqKehyQ

With the profiler I can see that my post parameters are well posted

```
plan    {"name":"fsggsfgsf","description":"gsfgsfgsf","_token":"7d089aca0203c60fe1e617488e532ac966101440"}
```

But I can't see any trace of an update query or something else.
If you have an idea, it will be great!

Many thanks,

Ben

Comment: You are missing the `persist()` call: `$em->persist($plan)` before the flush

Comment: I have the same behavior with the persist() call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to pass the queried plan to the form.

```
public function editAction($pid, $plid, Request $request)
{
    $plan = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('QArthFrameworkBundle:Plan')->findOneByPlid($plid);
    $project = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('QArthFrameworkBundle:Project')->findOneByPid($pid);

// Create a new one if not found
if (!$plan) $plan = new Plan();

// Build your form using queried or new plan
$form = $this->createForm(new PlanType(), $plan);

$form->handleRequest($request);

// Checks for POST as well as validity
if ($form->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($plan);  // To handle new plans, no impact for existting plans
        $em->flush();

// Rest is the same
```